# How to create a vertical line chart from fields on detail record

Tags: charts, crystal-reports

Trying to create a vertical line chart from data in 4 separate fields per Detail record.

I know how to do it using Excel (see image), trying to figure out how to do it using Crystal Charts.  Also, data is per detail record and I found that I can only insert a chart on a header or footer section.

I'm also not sure I'm using the correct verbiage as I can't seem to find an answer using google searches.

Thanks!

[image: Excel version of vertical line chart]

Comment: Please include the image in your post, not as an external link. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Niellles.  I wasn't able to attach an actual image as I don't have enough "reputation" yet.  This is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert chart into crystalreport from insert --> chart and choose type of chart and data will show in chart, chart insert in header and footer report but will contain all data you choose, also you can insert chart into hadear and footer group if you use group.
Note: Attached picture from crystal report

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a group to provide header/footer for each detail section.

Or, one of the Crystal Reports User Function Libraries listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) allows you to add special charts anywhere you wish within your report, feeding the data into the chart using formula logic.